# How to turn off all warning in python

Tags: python, warnings

I have this code:

```
import nsepython
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
print(nse_quote_ltp("RELIANCE"))
```

This code puts out this warning before printing out the result:

> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
> [www.nseindia.com:443](http://www.nseindia.com:443)
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.nseindia.com:443 "GET
> /api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES%20IN%20F%26O HTTP/1.1" 200
> 26695 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
> [www.nseindia.com:443](http://www.nseindia.com:443)
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.nseindia.com:443 "GET
> /api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE HTTP/1.1" 200 38950
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
> [www.nseindia.com:443](http://www.nseindia.com:443)
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.nseindia.com:443 "GET
> /api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES%20IN%20F%26O HTTP/1.1" 200
> 26695 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
> [www.nseindia.com:443](http://www.nseindia.com:443)
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.nseindia.com:443 "GET
> /api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE HTTP/1.1" 200 38950

```
2387
```

How can i turn off this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your logging level set to DEBUG, and if you're using a framework like Flask, it will use Python's built-in logging mechanism to output its messages at the appropriate level. Try this instead:

```
import nsepython
import warnings
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
print(nse_quote_ltp("RELIANCE"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.